# Simple file and folder view in C#

Tags: c#, shell, treeview, icons, directory

I have seen an application recently what had two simple controls (a treeView and a detailed ListView) what were used for listing directories and files. I know how to do this, but it had another nice feature other than listing files: it loaded info from the system shell, like icons of folders, file specifications (file types mostly, inherited from the system, so if I had an application what modified the SVG file type to "Unknown vectorgraphic stuff" then it showed all SVG file's type as this string before).

I would like to ask You, that how could I make these features easily without using any third party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the file icon, use **System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon**.
2. To get the file type, you need to use the Win32 **SHGetFileInfo** function.
3. To get date modified, file size, etc, you can use **DirectoryInfo** and **FileInfo** classes.

You can also consider using ready-made controls like [Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) which show files/folders like this with same icons, details, menus, etc

Comment: Thanks. That Shell Megapack looks like the best solution, will try it!

Answer (score 1):

you can get icon for a file by System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()...

Comment: Yes I know it but it's kinda frustrating to add any icon with this. Isn't there some kind of automated version of this? I mean extracting the icon and also adding the icon to the node with a simple command?

Comment: well - I guess you could get all icons for current view and put them into an ImageList of the treeview, then assign image IDs to the nodes.

But I'd do owner drawing of the treeview nodes, and on drawing each node I'd retrieve the icon of the file/directory and draw it before item text.

Comment: Isn't that kinda slow?
And also, for the treeView it only needs the folder icons. My bigger problem is the listView, where it should get ALL icons of the files in there, with file type too...